# Dual-licensing on a GPL software

Tags: licensing, software, france, gpl

I've been developing a software for 4 year, and I have spread parts of it under a GPL license for 2 years *without being aware of it* (it's complicated) since the beginning of the project.

I built it in partnership with a foundation, which put money on this, at the condition to put it under GPL : I've seen the contract made between my company (which is a public school) and the foundation few months ago.

I've built a significant number of things upon this GPL version since, without knowing it was going to be GPL too, and was about to use it for commercial purpose.

Is there any way to use dual licensing on that case, in USA ?

*Disclaimer : I'm in France, so if there's any french folks around, I'm more interested about the french law ; just replace GPL with [CeCILL_v1](http://www.cecill.info/licences/Licence_CeCILL_V1-fr.html) (GPL equivalent in France).*

Comment: You should contact the owner of the software and ask them how much they will sell a less restrictive license to their software for.

Comment: @mikeazo Sorry for not being clear : I'm the developer of the software. I edited the question to reflect this !

Comment: My comment still stands. Contact the owner of the copyright to see if they will license it. Or check your contract and see if you can reimplement it without looking at the source. You may want to talk to a lawyer though about that option.